# Error code 1111: Invalid use of group function sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

so I'm trying to compute the total cost per location by multiplying the sum of each item used with their respective price, this code is working for now :

```
create view location_costs as 
select
City as location, 
participant_item.SederStaple as item, 
sum(ItemAmount) as quantity,
item.ItemPrice*sum(ItemAmount) as price
from participant_item
inner join item 
on participant_item.SederStaple=item.SederStaple
group by item, location
order by location;
```

but I need to compute the sum of all of the total prices by location, so I'm adding the sum statement to my code :

```
create view location_costs as 
select
City as location, 
participant_item.SederStaple as item, 
sum(ItemAmount) as quant,
sum(item.ItemPrice*sum(ItemAmount)) as price
from participant_item
inner join item 
on participant_item.SederStaple=item.SederStaple
group by item, location
order by location;
```

and it's not working anymore:

> error code 1111, invalid use of group function sql

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the  multipication *before* the `sum()`:

```
select City as location, pi.SederStaple as item, 
       sum(ItemAmount) as quantity,
       sum(ItemAmount * i.ItemPrice) as price
from participant_item pi inner join
     item i
     on pi.SederStaple = i.SederStaple
group by item, location
order by location;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases and used them for the columns that you qualified.  You should qualify *all* column references in a query that references multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the sum inside the sum:

```
select
  pi.City as location, 
  pi.SederStaple as item, 
  sum(pi.ItemAmount) as quant,
  sum(i.ItemPrice * pi.ItemAmount) as price
from 
  participant_item pi
  inner join item i on pi.SederStaple = i.SederStaple
group by pi.City, pi.SederStaple
order by location;
```

In tidying up your aliasing I've guessed at which table these things came out of (i figured an item wouldn't have a city or a quantity, but a participant would) - you might need to tweak things a bit. Always fully alias your queries. It stops them mysteriously failing if in the future someone adds another column to a table with the same name

Also, while MySQL is quite happy to use aliases (location, item) in its group by, other databases aren't; keep the original names for your group by to make sure when your next job uses SQL Server you aren't caught out by this mysql-only "feature"